# How can i assign an object as a property of another object in nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, object, authentication

I am trying to assign an object 'user' as a property of another object 'req.user' like this (req.user = user) in a custom authentication function 'auth' so i can easily use it in a route '/users/me' to send a specific user profile.Here are my codes snippet.I will be so gratefull if i can get a valid help from any one here as soon as possible.

CODE 1 - The Authentication code

```
`const auth = async(req,res,next)=>{
    try{
        const token = req.header('Authorization').replace('Bearer ','')
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token,'Mysignupstring')
        const user = User.findOne({_id:decoded._id,'tokens.token':token})
        if(!user){
            throw new Error
        }
        req.user = user // Where am having issues 

        next()
    }
    catch(e){
        res.status(401).send('Pls Authenticate')
    }
}`
```

CODE 2 - Is the route code

```
   router.get('/users/me',auth,async(req,res)=>{
     res.send(req.user)


  })
```

CODE 3 - Is the Error code

```
(node:6464) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
```

I will be glad to have your help shortly.

Comment: your `findOne()` call is not leveraging `await`, hence you have an async issue

Comment: Show us the implementation for `User.findOne` method.

Comment: Thanks a million LostJon and Rantul Sharker! You guys spotted it.AM so gratful.Stakeoverflow is super good.Am thankful